# Frobenius theorem to prove that flat connection admits a local basis of flat sections

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $\xi = \left(\pi, E, M  \right)$ be a vector bundle of rank $r$ with connection $\nabla$. Let $U \subset M$ be a trivializing open set and $\{ s_1, \dots , s_k \}$ and $\{ s_1' , \dots , s_k' \}$ be two basis of local sections for $\xi$. Denoting by $A = \left[a^i_j\right] \in C^\infty\left(U, GL(r) \right)$ the matrix of change of basis so that $s'_i = \sum_j a_i^j s_j$. Denoting by $\Omega, \Omega'$ the curvature 2-forms, they are related by 
>   $$ \Omega' = A^{-1} \Omega A\,.$$
>   Using this and that 
>   $$\omega' = A^{-1} \omega A + A^{-1} dA\,, $$ 
>   where $\omega$ is the curvature 1-form, show that if $\nabla$ is a flat connection then around any point $p$ one can find a local basis of flat connections.

Moreover, a hint is given: use the condition $\omega'=0$ to define an integrable distribution in $U \times GL(r)$ and apply Frobenius.

What I thought was that since the connection is flat, then $\Omega' = \Omega= 0$. However, $\Omega = d \omega + \omega \wedge \omega \implies d \omega = - \omega \wedge \omega$ (and the same expression holds for $\omega'$). This tells us that $\omega'$ is a differential ideal and the distribution defined by $D= \mathrm{span} \{ X \in \mathfrak{X}(U) : \omega'(X) = 0 \}$ is involutive and therefore by Frobenius is integrable, but this doesn't seem to get me anywhere...

Overall, I think I'm missing something that should be obvious since my distribution is not even in $U\times GL(r)$, however, I'm at a loss on what such a distribution would be, so any pointers on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You practically solved the problem yourself... The distribution $D$ you defined is indeed integrable, which exactly means that there exist many locally parallel sections.

Comment: Note that the $\omega$ given here is a local matrix-valued $1$-forms (given a particular frame of sections), not a global matrix-valued $1$-form on the frame bundle of $E$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Start with a basis $\{s_1,\dots,s_r\}$ of sections on $U$. You want to define new sections $s_i' = \sum a_i^j s_j$ so that the connection form $\omega'$ with respect to the new basis $\{s_i'\}$ vanishes on $U$. This is now a differential system on $U\times GL(k)$ whose integral manifolds will give you the possible graphs of $A=(a_i^j)$ as functions of $x\in U$. (This approach is typically credited to E. Cartan, not too surprisingly.)

Comment: is the following correct: we want a new basis whose connection 1-form vanishes on $U$. This is given by the differential system $\omega' = A^{-1} \omega A + A^{-1} dA = 0 $. Multiplying everything by $A$ on the right yields $\omega A + dA = \alpha = 0$. To see that this defines an involutive distribution, we take its differential and obtain $d\omega A - \omega \wedge dA = \Omega A - \omega \wedge \omega A - \omega \wedge dA = \Omega A  - \omega \wedge \alpha$, and since the connection is flat we have that $\Omega = 0$. Therefore, we conclude that the initial system is integrable.

Comment: Well, you mean multiplying on the left. But this looks good. Now you need to argue that the integral manifolds project submersively onto $U$ so that you can recover them as graphs of the functions $A$.

Comment: I'm not seeing how to prove that the integral manifold projects submersively onto $U$. I thought of picking a chart for $U$, then distribution that we just proved to be involutive is of the form $\partial_{x^i} + \partial(a^j_k)/\partial x^i \partial_{a^j_k}$, with $i=1,\dots , r$. This implies that our integral submanifold is of the form $\{ (p, B) \in U \times GL(r) : A(p) - B = 0  \}$. If this is true, then the projection onto $U$ would always have maximum rank so it is a submersion. However, here I already assumed beforehand that the integral submanifold corresponds to the graphs of $A$.

Comment: Hint: Suppose some $v$ in the tangent space to an integral manifold satisfies $\pi_*(v)=0$. Recall that $A^{-1}dA$ is the Maurer-Cartan form for $GL(r)$.